# how to parse the json object with a function taking splat arguments in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, splat

I am trying to parse a json object with a userdefined function function func (obj /*, *args*/) {...} which takes splat arguments. I am stucked with this code.

```
function func (obj /*, *args*/) {

  pobj= JSON.parse(obj)
  var star_args = Array.prototype.slice.call (arguments, func.length);

  alert(pobj.name);
   //outputs name Tintin

  for (i=0;i<star_args.length;i++){
     alert(pobj.star_args[i]);
   }   

}

var json = '{"name":"Tintin","addr":"Kausaltar"}'

//function call with a json object
func(json,'name','addr');
```

the output is
--> alert pop-up with Tintin
followed by error

```
/*
Exception: pobj.star_args is undefined
func@Scratchpad/1:10
@Scratchpad/1:18
*/
```

So, my question is how to I access this json object elements with

```
pobj.star_args[i]
```

I know Javascript parser starts from left to right so it thorws an exveption.

Please anybody, help !! . I tested the code in scratch pad.

Comment: do you want to print `"name", "addr"` values ?

Comment: `for ( i=0;i<star_args.length;i++){ console.log( star_args[i] , pobj[ star_args[i]] ); }`

Comment: _thanks [rab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1722625/rab)_ it worked !!  

Exact answer I seek.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the line

```
alert(pobj.star_args[i]);
```

to

```
alert(star_args[i]);
```

Explanation:`star_args` is a local variable; it isn't part of the `pobj` object. So you just refer to it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code @zerOnepal, which will work for you.

```
<script>

function func (obj /*, *args*/) {

  pobj= JSON.parse(obj);
  var star_args = Array.prototype.slice.call (arguments, func.length);

  alert(pobj.name);
   //outputs name Tintin

 for(var k in pobj)
    if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(pobj, k))
        alert(k + " = "+ pobj[k]);  // k -> key and pobj[k] -> value 
}

var json = '{"name":"Tintin","addr":"Kausaltar"}'

//function call with a json object
func(json,'name','addr');

</script>
```

I hope this will help you.